# Display records and counts from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

My requirement is in this link [Requirement](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73ac4/1) . If we run the query, we will get only Chennai and Pune with Count 3 respectively because regionid of chennai and pune is present in table leads. But i need to show Bangalore and Delhi as 0 as well. How do I do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not getting Banglore and Delhi as 0 because you are joining the tables by `region_id` while those `region_id`<sup>(1)</sup> are not available in `Leads` tables so you will get `vehicle_id` = `NULL` for Banglore and Delhi ([**See this**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73ac4/9)). So when you write `WHERE B.vehicle_id = 2` you will not get Banglore and Delhi in your result. So removing `WHERE` condition will give you your desired result ([**See this**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73ac4/4)). If you want to keep that condition you can do that by using `Region.vehicle_id = 2` instead of `Leads.vehicle_id = 2`.

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73ac4/8).

<sub>(1) `region_id` of Banglore and Delhi.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

You can use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT A.region_name, COUNT(B.ID)
FROM TableA A 
LEFT JOIN TableB B
ON A.ID = B.ID
GROUP BY A.ID
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7623a/5)

Comment: Hi All, My requirement is in this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73ac4/1 . If we run the query, we will get only Chennai and Pune with Count 3 respectively because regionid of chennai and pune is present in table leads. But i need to show Bangalore and Delhi as 0 as well. How do I do that

Comment: @SanjaiPalliyil - Did you see the another answer?